# Create App with Ionic2-Angular2 front and ASP.NET core Back?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

how can I create app with Ionic2-Angular2 front-end and ASP.NET core Back-end? in same server. Also I what about multi-platform application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In ASP.NET you'll create a web API, that will be consumed from angular code. Here is how you create a web API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Angular, more precisely the JavaScript which will be generated, does not "know" what kind of back end is used. There just will be an URL and the method how to access it. Your communication will probably embrace HTTP GETs and POSTs. 
As long as the resource is accessible with one of the methods,
it does not matter if it is

- a static file (post would not make sense in this case)
- a PHP script
- or ASP.NET Backend
- or something else.